# Call javascript from asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, callback

How can i call a javascript function from a mvc controller similar
to what you would do in webforms with ICallbackHandler?

Is it possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller actions cannot call javascript functions. They return action results. Javascript code should be contained on the client side. So if you want to call a javascript function that should execute under certain circumstances you could subscribe for the corresponding event and when this event is triggered call the function.

For example if you wanted to call a javascript function when a button is clicked using jQuery you could do the following:

```
$(function() {
    // subscribe for the click event
    $('#someId').click(function() {
        // the button is clicked => execute some javascript function here
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I already know this and it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @Andrei, then probably you could explain your problem because in your question you are asking how to use some feature that no longer exists in ASP.NET MVC? How about explaining what you are trying to achieve in the first place so that we can offer adapted solutions for MVC?

Comment: Hah, yea. As I said, I want to call a javascript function after some time in a returned view. I want to update a div after some time without having the client constantly asking whether the information has arrived. Is that possible? Or I should go with asking every 5 secs or some? My problem is quite real-time and i will need to ask maybe once per second or so, and that's bad. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Andrei, you could poll the server for updates using AJAX at regular intervals or use a push model where the server would automatically send notifications to the client using [COMET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)). In HTML5 there is the [WebSocket API](http://websocket.org/) which allows you to achieve push notifications.

Comment: Aaa, i didn't know about html5 notifications. But polling like once per second sounds like too much traffic, isn't it? It must be a better solution, i will check html5 websockets, sounds like the fair solution. Thanks again.